# Attaching .txt to MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, email-attachments, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a .txt file stored in Documents Folder and I want to send it by  MFMailComposeViewController with next code in the body of `-sendEmail` method:

```
NSData *txtData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dataBase" ofType:@"txt"]];
        [mail addAttachmentData:txtData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataBase.txt"]];
```

When Mail composer appears I can see attachment in the mail body but I receive this mail without attachment. Maybe it is wrong MIME-type for .txt attachment or something wrong with this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];        
        NSString *txtFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc.txt"];
NSData *noteData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath];
        MFMailComposeViewController *_mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [_mailController setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ABC"]];
        [_mailController setMessageBody:_messageBody
                                 isHTML:NO];
        [_mailController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        [_mailController addAttachmentData:noteData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"abc.txt"];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

In Swift 3, you can send mail with attachment like this

```
@IBAction func emailLogs(_ sender: Any) {
    let allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = allPaths.first!
    let pathForLog = documentsDirectory.appending("/application.log")

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        mail.setToRecipients(["recipient@email.com"])
        mail.setSubject("Application Logs")
        mail.setMessageBody("Please see attached", isHTML: true)

        if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathForLog) {
            mail.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "text/txt", fileName: "application.log")
        }

        self.present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And then dismiss the composer controller on a result

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Make sure to subscribe to this delegate

```
MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
```